# Sending a body with a GET request using fetch

Tags: javascript, http, axios, get, fetch

I'm a new developer but even I know that sending a get request with a body (while possible) is a bad idea for several reasons. But since I sit low on the totem pole, I might have to submit to my senior who is asking me to hit our internal API endpoint with a GET request and a body. He specifically asks not to send the data as a url param. Its only two key value pairs, well under 200 characters. Could someone give a concise argument I could bring to my senior as to why a Post request with a body, or using query params would be a better option?

I know Axios doesn't even support a body with a GET request, so I thought if I do have to do this, perhaps the fetch api would be a possibility?

Comment: Forget all the ivory tower people say about caching and idempotence and stuff like that - iIf libraries like Axios don't allow it, *that's* why it's a bad idea.

Comment: If you want a non-concise answer with lots of background and practical reasons, I wrote this: https://evertpot.com/get-request-bodies/ . And yeah your main issue is going to be that browsers just don't support it, so you don't have a choice.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.